# MYSQL: How do I set a date (makedate?) with month, day, and year

Tags: mysql, date

I have three columns, y, m, and d (year, month, and day) and want to store this as a date.

What function would I use on mySQL to do this?

Apparently makedate uses year and day of year (see below), but I have month.

I know I can use STR_TO_DATE(str,format), by constructing the string from (y,m,d), but I would guess there is an easier way to do it.

REFERENCES

[MAKEDATE(year,dayofyear)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_makedate)

Returns a date, given year and day-of-year values. dayofyear must be greater than 0 or the result is NULL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you can use a string in the proper format:

```
UPDATE table SET my_date = '2009-12-31';
```

**Edit:** Yeah you can, just verified it in MySQL 5.1.

Answer (score 5):

It isn't high on readability but the following would work:

```
SELECT'1900-01-01' + INTERVAL y-1900 YEAR + INTERVAL m-1 MONTH + INTERVAL d-1
DAY FROM ...
```

Not sure that this any more efficient than using CONCAT and STR_TO_DATE.

Answer (score 2):

i hope this wil work out..

```
str_to_date( concat( year( curdate( ) ) , '-', month( a.dob ) , '-', day( a.dob ) ) , '%Y-%m-%d' )
```

Where a.dob is my column's name which has DATE